# Is the equality $(0,1]\cup(1,2)=(0,2)$ true?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I believe this is true because the first set contains everything up to and including $1$ and the second contains everything from $1$ onwards.

Comment: Yes it is true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Um... yes?

If $a \in (0,1]$ then $a \in (0,2)$ so $(0,1] \subset (0,2)$.

If $a \in (1, 2)$ then $a \in (0,2)$ so $(1,2) \subset (0,2)$.

So $(0,1] \cup (1,2) \subset (0,2)$.

If $b \in (0,2)$ then $b > 0$ and $b < 2$ and either 1) $b > 1$ or 2) $b \le 1$.

If 1) $b \in (1,2)$ and $b \in (0,1] \cup (1,2)$

If 2) $b \in (0,1]$ and $b \in (0,1] \cup (1,2)$

So $(0,2) \subset (0,1] \cup (1,2)$.

So $(0,1] \cup (1,2) = (0,2)$.

Or...

$(0,1] = \{x| 0< x \le 1\}; (1,2) = \{x| 1< x < 2\}$ so $(0,1] \cup (1,2) = \{x| 0<x\le 1 \text{ or } 1<x < 2\} = \{x| 0< x< 2\} = (0,1)$.

Answer (score 1):

This is only true if you work with classical logic.  If the background logic is intuitionistic then the equality $(0,1]\cup(1,2)=(0,2)$ may not hold.  This is related to the failure of the [law of trichotomy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trichotomy_(mathematics)).

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be true. To prove it, you generally need two steps:

1) Let $x\in(0,1]\cup(1,2)$. Then  $0<x\le 1$ or $1<x<2$. In either case, $x\in(0,2)$.

2) Let $x\in (0,2)$. Then either $x\le 1$ or $x>1$. Thus $x\in(0,1]$ or $x\in(1,2)$, so $x\in(0,1]\cup(1,2)$.

Depending on the level or rigor, it is important to be able to prove claims like this even if they appear obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Let $A,B\subset X$. Then $A\cup B:=\{x\in X\ \colon\  x\in A\ \vee\ x\in B\}$.

In yours case we have: $A=(0,1]$ and $B=(1,2)$.

It means that: $(0,1]\cup(1,2)=\{x\in\mathbb{R}\ \colon\ x\in (0,1]\ \vee\ x\in (1,2)\}=(0,2)$.

Note that, since $1\in (0,1]$ then $1\in (0,1]\cup(1,2)$.